# Firebase Warning: Permission denied for a user authenticated as anonymous

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Sorry if my question is already answered. I read the official documentation and I did a lot of web searching, but I can't find a solution.

I have an application web hosting in Google Firebase showing a list of computer science terms and definitions. When the user click on a term, the app show the definitions associated to that term.

I created two users: One as an editor, and other one as an authenticated anonymous. The editor can writer and read on the database. Anonymous can read but can't write on the database. So far, all is working, when the anonymous user make click on a term, he see on screen the definitions, but the Google Chrome console log the message "FIREBASE WARNING: set at… failed: permission_denied".

[image]

These are my Firebase rules:

```
{
   "rules": {   
      "terms": {  
          ".read": "auth != null",  
          ".write": "auth != null && (!data.exists() || data.child('owner').val() === auth.uid)", 
    }
  }
}
```

I don't want to use true for read and writer for every user. I want an authenticated anonymous with only read permission, and a editor user with read and write permission. The app is working, but still Firebase is printing this warning on the Google Chrome console.

Thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: That warning is implying that a `set()` is happening when the term is clicked -- can you check to make sure you're not accidentally trying to write to the DB at a different time than you expect?

Comment: Thanks @michael-bleigh, you pointed me the right way.  I'm working with Firebase and React. When the user is clicking a term, React rewrite the state component object for some internal flag of the applicaction. I was implementing that with setState using an arrow function, I don't know why but this was triggering a "set" action against Firebase.  I rewrite the state object, and now the anonymous user can read the data without problems. Now:     this.setState({
      showCreate: false,
      selectedTerm: newTerm,
    });